# Set up recurring meeting in outlook for multiple dates of the month

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, meetings

How would I set up a recurring meeting in Microsoft Outlook for specific numerical dates of the month? For instance, if I wanted to set up a meeting to always occur on the 13th *and* 28th of each month, how might I accomplish that? If this isn't possible, I can always create separate meetings to occur on each date, but I'm curious if there's a way to set this up.

Comment: The only way I have found (having done this a lot) is to make one appointment, save it, and then copy it, next date - paste, next date - paste,  . ....  etc.

Comment: @John Okay; thanks for that info. That might be what I have to do in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook recurring appointments have to be in the same week and on the same day. This does not work well for me.

The only way I have found (having done this a lot) is to make one appointment, save it, and then copy it.

Now move to the next date and paste, next date and paste, and so on. I can fill up several months of appointments this way in about 20 minutes.

I know it is a pedestrian method, but research has left me with this as the only practical alternative.

Comment: "pedestrian method"... Ahhhh!! Is that one of those pretty British insults? :')

Comment: The term is not an insult- just a friendly colloquialism